# Quick way to read a tab-delimited file and sort by date column using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

What is the best/quickest way to read a tab-delimited file and process only a few columns?

Sample:

```
Name\tAddress\tCit\t\State\Zip\Date of Move
```

I am looking to only get column1 and colum6 for the next 30 days
(Name, Date of Move and sort by Date of Move's scheduled in the next 30 days...).

I have played with [Get-Content](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx) | [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx) and have not had any luck...

#### UPDATE

I was able to convert a tabbed file to [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Once I have the CSV file, I have done the following to get only the columns I need.

PS D:> import-csv .\test.csv | Select "Name", " MoveDate", "Address"
 | Sort-Object "MoveDate"

This returns the columns I need only, but does not sort by date...the date field sorts by string so.

1/12/2010
1/13/2010

I need it sorted as a datetime field...

My sample data looks like this in that field...

```
 9/30/2009 12:21
```

How do I get it to sort by actual date?

Preferably return only the dates from today + 30 days.

Comment: Look at Keith's comment. Then you have a complete solution.

Answer (score 10):

[ConvertFrom-Csv](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849890.aspx) has a -Delimiter parameter. You should be able to specify tab. It returns objects, so you'd pipe it to "[sort](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849912.aspx) Date".

A tab is specified by "`t". So try this:

```
ConvertFrom-Csv  .\test.csv -Delimiter "`t" | Sort-Object MoveDate
```

Comment: Mike, Sweet, I am 90% there.

It does not sort by date...the date field sorts by string so.

1/12/2010
1/13/2010

I need it sorted as a datetime field....

My sample data looks like this in that field... 
9/30/2009 12:21

Any ideas to get it to sort by actual date ? (not string where 1 is first 2 2nd etc..)

Preferably return only the dates from today + 30 days.

Comment: Give Sort-object a hint e.g. `... | Sort {[DateTime]$_.MoveDate}`  Once Sort knows that it is sorting Dates instead of strings, it'll do a better job.

Comment: Awesome.  I haven't ever used that kind of thing with sort.  I love learning new PowerShell goodies.

Comment: And for that last part...

| where-object {[datetime]$_.MoveDate -lt (get-date).AddDays(30)}